# Toggle infinispan caches for dev or testing env

Tags: infinispan

I moved from EhCache to Infinispan and I have requirement that be able to toggle caches (not only globally but also for specific cache name).

Using EhCache there was a option `setDisable(Boolean)` to disable a cache.

I would like to achieve something similar with Infinispan, however I don't want to change my app code. I mean I don't want something like

```
if cache is enabled
  ...
else
  ...
```

I'm waiting to something that *NoOp* cache operation, like calling `put(key, object)` do nothing at all (not only storing, but no serialization, no computation) and same for others methods.

---

Since I'm using Spring integration I was thinking about using `CompositeCacheManager` with `NoOpCacheManager` fallback but current existing *Spring integration* uses *dynamic* cache creation, so `getCache(String)` never returns `null` (thus `NoOpCacheManager` is never used).

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `infinispan.embedded.cache.enabled` to `false`